# EventSubscriber doesn't get triggered on event

Tags: symfony, events

I'm using symfony 3.2.7, and wanting to store the information of every single email sent through the app (using Swift Mailer) in my database. I'm trying to use an EventSubscriber to do that, since Swift Mailer dispatches a `RESULT_SUCCESS` constant from the `Swift_Events_SendEvent` class when an email is successfully sent. But it just doesn't work.

The file containing the EventSubscriber is definitely processed when a mail is sent (to test that, I purposedly added wrong syntax in the file and I get a syntax error when a mail is sent), but the `onMailSent` function apparently isn't called, since the email information isn't stored in my database. And that same function works in another context, so the problem doesn't come from the function itself.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

SentMailsListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace Fidelise\SignUpBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Fidelise\SignUpBundle\Entity\EmailsHistory;
use Swift_Events_SendEvent;

class SentMailsListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_SUCCESS => 'onMailSent'];
    }

    public function onMailSent(Swift_Events_SendEvent $event)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $message = $event->getMessage();
        $email = new EmailsHistory();
        $email->setRecipient(key($message->getTo()));
        $email->setSubject($message->getSubject());
        $email->setBody($message->getBody());
        $email->setSender(key($message->getFrom()));
        $em->persist($email);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    mail_sent_subscriber:
        class: Fidelise\SignUpBundle\EventListener\SentMailsListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Are you sure that enum Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_SUCCESS is the correct subscriber key? I'm having trouble finding documentation but it seems to be a flag and so doesn't look right as an event name

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not entirely sure, but hopefully you'll know. Here's the file where Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_SUCCESS is defined: https://pastebin.com/uUx9Kfe6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should do is to register swiftmailer plugin. It is not an event listener of event dispatcher:

```php
<?php

namespace Fidelise\SignUpBundle\EventListener;

use Swift_Events_SendEvent;
use Swift_Events_SendListener;

class SentMailsListener implements Swift_Events_SendListener
{
    public function sendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $event): void
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
services:
    mail_sent_subscriber:
        class: Fidelise\SignUpBundle\EventListener\SentMailsListener
        tags:
            - { name: swiftmailer.default.plugin }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @VladRia. It works, the ```sendPerformed``` function is called. But I have another problem now; I can't seem to be able to use the entitiy manager: the first line ```$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();``` gives me an error saying that ```getDoctrine()``` isn't defined. Do you know how I can deal with that?

Comment: As your `SentMailsListener` is a service you are able to pass another services in its constructor. So you can pass an entity manager directly in the constructor of `SentMailsListener`. `SentMailsListener ... { private $em; public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) { $this->em = $em; }}` and use it in your `sendPerformed` (`$this->em->persist();`). https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

Comment: I've already read that somewhere else and tried it, but I get this error: ```Type error: Too few arguments to function Fidelise\SignUpBundle\EventListener\SentMailsListener::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\rpfc\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3124 and exactly 1 expected```. I guess I have to somehow pass the ```$em``` variable as an argument in ```services.yml```, but I don't know how. Any idea?

Comment: do you know how to fix that?

Comment: The simpliest would be to add `autowire: true` to `services: mail_sent_subscriber`. Or if you don't want to use autowiring you can add `arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]`. Here you can find more info https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html